# Android Studio doesn't apply code changes

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a simple method in the `MainActivity named` test()`, and then later I removed it 'cause it was not needed anymore. But after running the application again, I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method test()Landroidx/lifecycle/LiveData; in class Lcom/shaunyl/navigationtest/user/model/UserViewModel; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.shaunyl.navigationtest.user.model.UserViewModel' appears in /data/data/com.shaunyl.navigationtest/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dex)
at com.shaunyl.navigationtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:70)
```

at line 70 of the file MainActivity there's not such a method of course, because I just removed it. But android studio keeps marking it (like caching it somewhere in the code_cache folder and never taking track of it), preventing the application to start up.

I have tried to delete the .idea folder, invalidate caches and restart android studio, and even restart the emulator. Nothing worked.
Only thing that works is to wipe out emulator's data and restart it again.

But this is not a practical solution. Every time I write and then delete a method, or write and then delete a class, this issue pulls up.

Is there any solution to this annoying problem?
Thanks

Comment: try to `Build > Make Project` before running it

Comment: @MuhammadSabeelAhmed hello. As I've already stated, that action doesn't make it work

Comment: @Zain it doesn't make it work, not make project nor rebuild project

Comment: try `./gradlew clean`

Comment: @Noah I have tried `./gradlew cleanBuildCache` but with no success

Comment: this is a build failure, right? does building with the gradle wrapper (`./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`) work?

Comment: @Noah that didn't work either. I made it work by edit that specific line one more time. It's like Android Studio doesn't track all changes sometimes, I am not sure why. It doesn't happen always

Comment: Try cleaning the project and do a Rebuild. If this does not work then go to File->Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue and try everything I could think of without any success... Thanks

Comment: As you can see in the error message, the dex file in question with the obsolete reference to the removed method is on the device, not on your build area.

Simply uninstalling and reinstalling the app on the device should help. Or you can use the 'Clear storage' button in the app info view on the device.

Comment: @TeemuRossi You've gotten plenty of upvotes on your comment!  How about putting this comment as the Answer to better help others with the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on my original comment above:

As you can see in the error message, the dex file in question with the obsolete reference to the removed method is on the device, not on your build area.

Simply uninstalling and reinstalling the app on the device should help. Or you can use the 'Clear storage' button in the app info view on the device.